# Could we said python script is the same tha shell scripting?

Tags: python, bash, shell

If the definition of the shell is:

> In computing, a shell is a user interface for access to an operating
>   system's services. In general, operating system shells use either a
>   command-line interface (CLI) or graphical user interface (GUI),
>   depending on a computer's role and particular operation. It is named a
>   shell because it is the outermost layer around the operating system
>   kernel.

And shell scripting is:

> A shell script is a computer program designed to be run by the Unix
>   shell, a command-line interpreter.

Could we say correctly that a python script is a shell script to, but this is not a Bash script?

Comment: yes. there is also a shell builded on python named [xonsh](https://xon.sh/index.html)

Comment: Unfortunately this question allows of many opinions and no definitive answer, and so is likely to be closed. You may get answers from python-list@python.org, where it's on-topic for discussion.

Comment: The existence of a hybrid shell that can run Python doesn't make a Python program "a shell script."  By that definition, any program could be considered a shell script, and then we've completely lost the distinction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shell scripting is using shell commands, which is different than Python scripting.
Unlike Python scripts, shell scripts do not need a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)). Your quote explains it clearly:

> A shell script is a computer program designed to be run by the Unix
>   shell, a command-line interpreter.

It clearly defines shell scripts as they run by Unix shell. Python scripts on the other hand, are run by Python interpreter, not by the shell.

Therefore Python scripts are not shell scripts. Keep in mind that you use shell to run the Python code but shell actually forwards script content to Python interpreter, with the help of shebang.

Comment: Yes, ``bash`` scripts are also shell scripts since ``bash`` is a shell.

Answer (score 3):

Writing Python programs is not "shell scripting".  There is no OS shell involved in running a Python program.  Some people call Python (and other languages) a "scripting language," but that is a vague term with no clear definition.  Python is a programming language, and when you write Python programs, you are programming.

Comment: Then can we say bash script and shell script is the same only if the shell is bash?

Comment: A bash script is one kind of shell script.